# how to make a type which only extracts property values from the interface in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I exactly don't know how to express my intention in a single sentence, so I will try my best.

```
interface A {
  person: {
    name: string;
    age: number;
  },
  count: number
}

type B = Pick<A, 'person'>

// type B = {person: {name: string; age: number;}}
```

As we can see, if we use `Pick` utility type, type B has a key `person`.

What if I want to get rid of the key(person), and only want to have those property values like below type C?

```
 // type C which I want to make.
 type C = {
   name: string;
   age: number;
 }

 // something like StripKeyOut<Pick<A, 'person'>> is possible?
```

appreciate in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript has [Indexed Access Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html): `type B = A['person']`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnIA7QDOA9iAFyY67IhwC2EFhYUoA5gNxW5xuM0BXOgCNoXXAF8ANFQTEB4CiCGioWCVixgAngWQAhZAF40AbQDkBKCRDmAulgD0j6gD0A-EA)